# Find 4 values of columns in other sheet and get extra column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working with two tables in Excel. The sheet1 I have 5 columns and sheet2 there are 4 columns.

In sheet1 there are a lot of rows, so, I want to find the values of the columns of sheet2 in sheet1 and print the extra column that I do not have.

This is an example.

#### Sheet1

| B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| root1 | er | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| raw2 | dd | 2 | 4 | 4 |

#### Sheet2

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dd | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| ff | 3 | 4 | 2 |
| dd | 2 | 4 | 4 |

So, I want to search the values of the sheet2 in sheet1 and generate other column in sheet2, in E, with the value of column B in sheet1.

I tried to use VLOOKUP, but I get 4 columns with the info of column B in sheet1.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please also show your desired output and your formula attempt.

Comment: You probably need to use `INDEX()` & `MATCH()` Function with a `Boolean Logic`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `INDEX()` & `MATCH()` Function, check the following screenshots:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E1`

```
=IFERROR(
INDEX('Blad 1'!$B$1:$B$2,MATCH(1,
(A1='Blad 1'!$C$1:$C$2)*
(B1='Blad 1'!$D$1:$D$2)*
(C1='Blad 1'!$E$1:$E$2)*
(D1='Blad 1'!$F$1:$F$2),0)),
"Not Found")
```

---

**Note:** Assuming you wont have duplicates and since its an array formula, based on your excel version need to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode, **O365** & **Excel 2021** Users don't need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

---

Not sure about your Excel Version, but if you happen to have access to `MS365` then you can use `XLOOKUP()` function

[image]

---

• Formula can also be used in cell `E1` --> **Excel Dependent**

```
=XLOOKUP(1,
(A1='Blad 1'!$C$1:$C$2)*
(B1='Blad 1'!$D$1:$D$2)*
(C1='Blad 1'!$E$1:$E$2)*
(D1='Blad 1'!$F$1:$F$2),
'Blad 1'!$B$1:$B$2,
"Not Found")
```

---